# Windows batch script parse string inside single quotes separated by commas

Tags: parsing, batch-file, text

input.txt:

```
['Chinese Simplified', 'Traditional Chinese HK', 'Traditional Chinese TW', 'English', 'French', 'German', 'Indonesian', 'Italian', 'Korean', 'Malay', 'Portuguese', 'Portuguese Brasil', 'Russian', 'Spanish', 'Spanish Latin', 'Tagalog']
```

Desired output:

Chinese Simplified

Traditional Chinese HK

Traditional Chinese TW

English

French

ETC.

I tried something like this:

for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('findstr /c:, "input.txt"') do echo %%A >> output.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36607414.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=[]" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:'="!"
 FOR %%b IN (!line!) DO ECHO(%%~b
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36607414.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Read each line,assigning the first token delimited by brackets to `%%a`

Transfer to `line` for string-manipulation

Replace `'` with `"` using delayedexpansion to access run-time value of `line`

Use simple `for` to regurgitate resultant list of quoted items separated by spaces and commas; the `~` removes the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation great help.